# How to get data from a resultset if only one of the columns is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, resultset

I am trying to set information in some txts. My code is good when all columns are full but when a column is null there is a throw exception and code just doesn't run inside the try catch.

I know that the problem is a null column because the column `PhotoQ` is an optional data information for the user. So a solution, maybe load a defaultPhoto in all user accounts, but will spend store in the database.

Excuse my English I'm new XD.

Example code:

```java
try {
    PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pstm.setInt(1, userid);
    pstm.setInt(2, quizzid);
    pstm.setInt(3, NumQuest);
    ResultSet rs =pstm.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        fileBytes = rs.getBytes("PhotoQ");
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(fileBytes);
        Image im = image.getImage();
        Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(lblImage.getWidth(), lblImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);

        if (rs.getString("Optionsid").endsWith("1")) {
            txtaA.setText(rs.getString("Options"));
            txtaQuestion.setText(rs.getString("Question"));
            if (rs.getInt("Valid")==1) {
                ckbA.setSelected(true);
            }
            else {
                ckbA.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why your code wont run inside try/catch?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question and error are centered around `null` values for the `PhotoQ` and/or `Optionsid` columns.  You should be using explicit checks for nulls, for each column.  Only if a column be not `null` should you attempt to use the value.

Something along these lines should give you an idea of how you might handle this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    fileBytes = rs.getBytes("PhotoQ");
    if (fileBytes != null) {            
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(fileBytes);
        Image im = image.getImage();
        Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(lblImage.getWidth(), lblImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);
    }

    String optionsId = rs.getString("Optionsid");
    if (optionsId != null && optionsId.endsWith("1")) {
        txtaA.setText(rs.getString("Options"));
        txtaQuestion.setText(rs.getString("Question"));
        Integer valid = rs.getInt("Valid");
        if (valid != null && valid.intValue() == 1) {
            ckbA.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            ckbA.setSelected(false);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't be using try/catch for nullpointer exception a better option?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I don't think this would be better in any way at all.  You are suggesting handling _any_ column being null with _one_ blanket exception.  My method allows the developer to handle the logic for each column individually.

Comment: Exception handling is slower than checking for null value , yet its more readable than checking for null , imagine you are using builder pattern to build up huge object  , you will need to have nested if statements checking for each one to not be null, maybe in the case of only one value to be null check would be good but in general i believe checking for null would be so ugly

Comment: if I use if inside a try then variables come to be unused or Result set called allways throw exception, because filebyte =rs.getbyte(" ").we could fixe it with global varibles but exception always apear. Now I fixed the problem I will post it.

Comment: @StevenCanales I believed I addressed the problem you described.  If not, then maybe you should update your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen local variables was setting in unused when I used an if inside a tryCatch. So I believe that something not change for it, some code or something I dont know. so Im new in java and my code now is working for everybody in this beautyful website. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For fix this issue in my app. 
I use a wasnull() but this inside a try just for ask if a record come with a null field, I dont know if a try inside a try is properly but know is working!

code:

```
try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
        pstm.setInt(1, userid);
        pstm.setInt(2, quizzid);
        pstm.setInt(3, NumQuest);
        ResultSet rs =pstm.executeQuery();
        try {
            //move result set at first row
            rs.next();
             fileBytes = rs.getBytes("PhotoQ");
            //ask if result set contain null field
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
            // this variable is defined like globlal    
            nuller=1;
            }else {
                nuller=0;
            }
        } catch (Exception f) {

        }
         //reload resulset for begin again
        rs =pstm.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
              //here is thi – Tim Biegeleisen idea
            if (nuller==0) {
                fileBytes = rs.getBytes("PhotoQ");
                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(fileBytes);
                Image im = image.getImage();
                Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(lblImage.getWidth(), lblImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);
                lblImage.setIcon(newImage);
            }
```

//this code only work for a query with one row result. I use while because my 
//teacher example is with while. whe I get finish the system will change the code

Answer (score 0):

@StevenCanales,

You were on the right track you can use the wasNull() to check the value of the last column pulled from the result set.  However you do not need the additional try / catch.  You can do this all streamlined within the while block.

```
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
        pstm.setInt(1, userid);
        pstm.setInt(2, quizzid);
        pstm.setInt(3, NumQuest);
        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            fileBytes = rs.getBytes("PhotoQ");
            // ask if result set contain null field
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                // handle as you wish... throw an exception ?
            } else {
                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(fileBytes);
                Image im = image.getImage();
                Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(lblImage.getWidth(), lblImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);

                if (rs.getString("Optionsid").endsWith("1")) {
                    txtaA.setText(rs.getString("Options"));
                    txtaQuestion.setText(rs.getString("Question"));
                    if (rs.getInt("Valid") == 1) {
                        ckbA.setSelected(true);
                    } else {
                        ckbA.setSelected(false);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       //handle exception
    }
```

The while loop will handle walking the result set appropriately.  There isn't anything special you need to do to move to the first record or back or forward.